# How can I fix my corrupt app?

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, corrupt

When I was programing I steped on my power code and my computer shut off. Know when I went back onto eclips the gen file is empty and one of my layouts have no code in it? is there anyway to fix this? Or, is there anyway to get everything i need from the .apk that it exported to?
Please help me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open your .apk with winZip.

You'll have to restore your source from backup (or type it back in).